# Compare entirely two different models in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I have been working in Django template. I have been stuck here since quite some time now.

```
{% for i in LOOP %}
    {% if i == {{SECOND VARIABLE}} %}
    //Do Something
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

LOOP and second variable are entirely different. Is there something we can do? Is there some alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

Inside `{%if condition %}`, `condition` is Python code (sort of). So, assuming `SECOND_VARIABLE` was passed in the context,

```
 {% for i in LOOP %}
    {% if i == SECOND VARIABLE %}
```

should work